# OAuth2 gem: implementation for third party - access other accounts data in seek.com

Tags: ruby, oauth

I'm connecting to an API (seek.com.au) which uses OAuth2 for authentication. I struggled with OAuth2 gem for a while and I ended up writing the plain requests as will follow. Although this is working, I still would like to understand what was wrong with my initial OAuth2 implementation.

Here is my current working code, **the third party* relates to the fact that I'm accessing the API with an account that have access to other accounts. This logic is mainly implemented in the `scope` method (at the bottom of this snippet).

The following includes some extra logic, but the `get_grant` and `post_for_token` methods should include everything.

```
module Seek::Base

  CONFIG       = YAML.load_file "#{Rails.root}/config/seek.yml"

  HOST         = 'http://test.api.seek.com.au/v1/'

  REQUEST_URIS = {

    get_grant:        HOST + 'OAuth/auth',

    post_for_token:   HOST + 'OAuth/token',

    get_applications: HOST + 'advertiser/applications'

  }

  def uri_for(request, params = {})

    uri  = REQUEST_URIS[request]

    uri += '?' + params.to_param if params.any?

    URI.parse uri

  end

end

class Seek::OAuth2 # TODO? is instance needed?

  include Seek::Base

  # by account_id

  @@tokens = {}

  def initialize(account_id)

    @account_id = account_id 

  end

  def self.authenticate!(account_id)

    new(account_id).authenticate!

  end

  # eg: when a request responded that the token is expired

  def self.expire_token(account_id)

    @@tokens.delete account_id

  end

  ###########################################################################

  ############################### begin #####################################

  # authentication

  # see: http://developer.seek.com.au/docs/partner-api/api-methods/oauth-2.0

  def authenticate!

    @@tokens[@account_id] ||= begin

      grant = get_grant

      raise Exception.new(@error) if @error

      Rails.logger.info "Retrive token for #{@account_id}"

      post_for_token

    end

  end

private

  # part of t he authentication process

  # as we have one account for many entities, we use third party variation

  # see: http://developer.seek.com.au/docs/partner-api/api-methods/oauth2/auth

  def get_grant

    uri         = uri_for :get_grant, {response_type: :code, client_id: username, scope: scope}

    response    = Net::HTTP.get_response uri

    params      = response['location'].split('?').second

    @error      = params.split('error=').second

    @grant_code = params.split('code=').second

  end

  # part of the authentication process

  # see: http://developer.seek.com.au/docs/partner-api/api-methods/oauth2/token

  def post_for_token

    uri = uri_for :post_for_token

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}

    request.set_form grant_type: :authorization_code, code: @grant_code, redirect_uri: ''

    request.basic_auth username, password

    response = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).request request

    JSON(response.body)['access_token']

   end    

  ########################## end ############################################

  ###########################################################################

  def username

    CONFIG['credentials']['username']

  end

  def password

    CONFIG['credentials']['password']

  end

  ############## the scope method

  ############## I think I need to insert this in the OAuth request

  def scope

    "urn:seek:thirdparty:username:#{username},urn:seek:advertiser:identity:#{@account_id}"

  end

end
```

And here are the few lines (to replace the `authenticate!` method) that were meant to do the same, but sadly, OAuth returns `invalid_client`.

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(username, password, :site => 'http://test.api.seek.com.au/v1')

client.auth_code.authorize_url redirect_uri: ''

token = client.auth_code.get_token 'authorization_code_value',

          headers: {'Authorization' => %^Basic #{Base64.encode64 "#{username}:#{password}"}^ }
```

I think the problem relies in the `scope` method created by OAuth (see bottom of the first snippet), but I'm not sure and anyways I couldn't find a way to amend it.

I also opened [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/issues/125), but I think this is covered, just it's not documented (or I can't find it).

Comment: Just wondering how you ended up going with this? I've just started to look at the API, whilst not too familiar with oAuth or 2 in general I found their lack of documentation and extremely poor examples difficult to work with. They mention to use oAuth2 but they're certainly not following the standard work-flow and naming conventions. To top it all off their examples work off JavaScript which is full of errors.

I certainly see some face palming moments occurring soon. I'll be sure to share my experience although I'll be using PHP instead of Ruby.

Comment: thanks, I should have taken care of it, but I'm still hoping someone will come to the rescue

Comment: I actually managed to write a connector yesterday that interfaces with the API, handles the whole auth process and standard API calls.

The tricky thing that got me was the whole "it's OAuth2 blah blah blah" but it's actually modelled around it, so you've got the basic concept in place, essentially being a 2 step auth process but it doesn't function the same way as a standard oAuth2 client would (like twitter).

I didn't end up using any oAuth2 clients/libs I wrote my own using CURL with a lot of trial and error thanks to the poor documentation and the examples that don't work.

Comment: yes, I was not very happy with the seek doc as well, happy to know you solved your problems. I still would like to get it working with OAuth2 gem, I think it's possible somehow, I got very close but I'm missing some bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ruby (Rails) implementation

This implementation is not using any wrapper, I tried the gem OAuth2 but I was not able to get the grant code,
I presume because the third party implementation require a customization of the `scope` which I was not able to set with the gem.

```
module Api::Base

  CONFIG       = YAML.load_file "#{Rails.root}/config/api.yml"
  HOST         = 'https://api.com.au/v1/'
  REQUEST_URIS = {
    get_grant:        HOST + 'OAuth/auth',
    post_for_token:   HOST + 'OAuth/token',
    get_applications: HOST + 'advertiser/applications'
  }

  def uri_for(request, params = {})
    uri  = REQUEST_URIS[request]
    uri += '?' + params.to_param if params.any?
    URI.parse uri
  end

end

class Api::OAuth2
  include Api::Base

  # by account_id
  @@tokens = {}

  def initialize(account_id)
    @account_id = account_id
  end

  def self.authenticate!(account_id)
    new(account_id).authenticate!
  end

  # eg: when a request responded that the token is expired
  def self.expire_token(account_id)
    @@tokens.delete account_id
  end

  # authentication
  def authenticate!
    @@tokens[@account_id] ||= begin
      grant = get_grant
      raise StandardError.new(@error) if @error

      puts "Retrive token for #{@account_id}"
      post_for_token
    end
  end

private

  # part of t he authentication process
  # as we have one account for many entities, we use third party variation
  def get_grant
    uri          = uri_for :get_grant, {response_type: :code, client_id: username, scope: scope}
    http         = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    http.use_ssl = uri.port == 443
    puts "SSL not set for uri #{uri}" unless http.use_ssl?
    response     = http.get uri.to_s
    raise Exception.new(response.message) unless response.is_a? Net::HTTPFound

    params      = response['location'].split('?').second
    @error      = params.split('error=').second
    @grant_code = params.split('code=').second
  end

  # part of the authentication process
  def post_for_token
    uri      = uri_for :post_for_token
    request  = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'}
    request.set_form grant_type: 'authorization_code', code: @grant_code, redirect_uri: ''
    request.basic_auth username, password
    http = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
    http.use_ssl = uri.port == 443
    response = http.start {|http| http.request request}

    JSON(response.body)['access_token']
   end
  end

  def username
    CONFIG['credentials']['username']
  end

  def password
    CONFIG['credentials']['password']
  end

  def scope
    "urn:api:thirdparty:username:#{username},urn:api:advertiser:identity:#{@account_id}"
  end

end
```

I'm still planning to use OAuth 2, [I'll post my updates here if any](http://netengine.com.au/blog/OAuth2-third-party-implementation/)